# How to check if a command contains an url

Tags: macros, expl3, xparse, xstring

I need to check if a url is the argument of a command. My first instinct would be to convert the argument to a string, then check if "\url" is in that string. This is what I tried so far. The commented line causes a fatal error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse, xstring}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{ \checkurl }{ m }{
  \token_to_str:N #1 \\
  % \IfSubStr{ \token_to_str:N #1 }{ \textbackslash url }{ url }{ not~an~url } % checks if the string "\url" is in the argument
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% -----------------
\begin{document}
\checkurl{\url{https://google.com}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because `\textbackslash` is a text command to typeset a backslash, not "the backslash character". Being so it contains font selection commands and many other things that make the string comparison choke. You're using `expl3` syntax anyhow, so you can replace `\textbackslash` by `\c_backslash_str`, which is "the backslash character". Change this and the error goes away, but the output isn't correct yet.

Also, `\token_to_str:N` turns a *single* token into a string (it's TeX's `\string` primitive). The argument of your command is more than a single token (a token *list*), so you need to replace it by `\tl_to_str:n` (the signature also changed from `N` to `n` because we expect a braced argument, not a single token).

Finally, you need to make sure that `\IfSubStr` will work properly: you need to issue `\fullexpandarg` before using `\IfSubStr` to ensure that `\tl_to_str:n` and `\c_backslash_str` will expand *before* `xstring` tries to compare them. And you also need to use the starred variant of `\IfSubStr`, because otherwise it will do a *token* comparison, and the tokens you get from `\tl_to_str:n { \url }` are all catcode 12 tokens, while the tokens from `\c_backslash_str url` will be one catcode 12 and three catcode 11 tokens, and the matching will fail.

But hey, you're already using `expl3`, so why not simply use `\str_if_in:nn`? :-)
It will do the proper conversion of the argument to a string of catcode 12 tokens, and it's a *lot* faster:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \checkurl } { m }
  {
    \token_to_str:N #1 \\
    \str_if_in:nnTF {#1} { \url }
      { url } { not~an~url }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\checkurl{\url{https://google.com}}
\end{document}
```